Question regarding finding the rate of depreciation in a half-life equation. This uses logarithms but I am unsure how to arrive at the answer given.
This question is from a chapter regarding logarithms. I have correctly answered part (a) of the question, which simply involves substituting the variables for the values given, so I need no help with that one. The answer to it is $4,267.
But part (b) baffles me as to the actual process used to arrive at the answer. I know I must use logarithms at whatever base I'd like, so long as I take the same base in both sides of the equation. That is, on a calculator, it could be a common log or a natural log.
Besides being a chapter on logarithms, I know to use a logarithm because it "undoes" a value that has been raised to a power.
Part (b) is independent of the answer in part (a), so I know I don't actually need to provide the answer to (a) to solve (b), but I thought I'd include it to show that I don't actually need that answer.
Any help would be appreciated.


If (b) is independent of (a) the question can be made more focussed. Not having defined "half life" you could try to come up with an equation that needs to be solved. Which type of logarithm we use we shall see then.

Hint
According to the definition of half life,$S=\frac{1}{2}C$.
Thus
$$\frac{C}{2}=C(1-r)^6$$
Hope you'll easily solve this
